# Subdivision not working as expected

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have subdivided my mesh and in two spots it seems to be sticking to the original vertices:

[image: Annotated screenshot showing the two spots]

I tried deleting the surfaces surrounding that area and remaking them with no success. How can I make this issue go away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if you have any overlapping vertices. If you look at the 2 other shapes, they are okay.

##### Select All with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>M</kbd> and merge by distance.

Alternatively you may have some "Edge Crease" on edges. So enable Overlay to check for that.

[image: Mesh edit mode overlays]

You can also check the exact value of a crease in your geometry on the side panel.

Select edge and check creasing for both vertices and edges:

[image: Select edge and check creasing for both vertices and edges]

Comment: Thank you. It did, indeed, seem to be solved by merging vertices.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. My apologies for not accepting the answer earlier. I am new to this StackExchange and after you brought it to my attention it took a while for me to find how to accept. Thanks again.